# How to click on multiple links within a table using HtmlUnit Java

Tags: java, hyperlink, web-scraping, htmlunit

I want to access table values on this website using HtmlUnit and Java:

http://www.lipidmaps.org/data/chemdb_lm_text_ontology.php?ABBREV=PA(40:10)

For example, I want to be able to click on "LMGP10010453" under lm_id

My solution for other problems of this nature would include looking for the xpath or id for the element, but in this case, since I would need to access many other websites in which the lm_id will not be this exact one, I can't just hardcode an xpath link. For example, on this link the lm_id is different: http://www.lipidmaps.org/data/chemdb_lm_text_ontology.php?ABBREV=PI(27:0)

Does anyone have any ideas how I can access certain elements of a table (preferably just the upper leftmost element) and click on a link within it?

Answer (score 0):

To start things off, try getting the table via the id. (Alternatively you can just get the table via XPath.)

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.lipidmaps.org/data/chemdb_lm_text_ontology.php?ABBREV=PA(40:10)");
HtmlTable table = page.getHtmlElementById("table id");
```

You can then access the upper left element using table.getCellAt()

```
HtmlTableCell upperLeft = (HtmlTableCell) table.getCellAt(2,1);
```

You can take the link from the table element like this:

```
List<HtmlLink> links = upperLeft.getHtmlElementsByTagName("a"); 
String href = links.get(0).getHrefAttribute();
```

The above code will get you the href of the link you are trying to click.

Finally, you can get an anchor from the href you found, and click it.

```
HtmlAnchor anchor = page.getAnchorByHref(href);
page = anchor.click();
```

You may need to adjust my example code to match the table you are working with but it should typically work fine.

Hope this helps!